# JSON and Node in Swift how can implement filters for categories in GET request

Tags: json, node.js, swift, alamofire

Simply, I want to filter full json array to three categories.

Let me show you what am talking about

```
var menu = [
    {
        id: "coffe",
        name: "Espresso",
        description: "",
        image: ''
    },
    {
        id: "coffe",
        name: "Latte",
        description: "",
        image: ''
    },
    {
        id: "coffe-nosugar",
        name: "Hot Chocolate",
        description: "",
        image: ''
    },
{
        id: "tea",
        name: "Red Tea",
        description: " ",
        amount: "0.0",
        image: ''
    },
        {
        id: "tea",
        name: "Green Tea",
        description: " ",
        amount: "0.0",
        image: ''
    },
                {
        id: "fresh-juice",
        name: "Orange",
        description: "",
        amount: "0.0",
        image: ''
    }
]
```

Now, Can anyone please tell me how can I phrase this data to three categories

- Coffee
- Tea
- Juice

For now I am using this in my nodeJS

```
app.get('/menu', (req, res) => res.json(menu))
```

To Show all Inventory items without any filters by simply go to 
http://APIurl/menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var menu: [MenuItems] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            
        fetchInventory { menu in
// Answer: This is will eliminate items with id == "1".
            menu = (menu?.filter { $0.id != "1"})! 
//Show All Items
            self.menu = menu! 

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Thanks to **Wonjung Kim**! See full post here: [How can I implement an array filter with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165523/how-can-i-implement-an-array-filter-with-swift)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Menu: Codable {

    var id: String
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var image: String
    var amount: String
    var category: String
}

var menu = "[\r\n  {\r\n    \"name\": \"Espresso\",\r\n    \"id\": \"coffe\",\r\n    \"description\": \"\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Coffee\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"name\": \"Latte\",\r\n    \"id\": \"coffe\",\r\n    \"description\": \"\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Coffee\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": \"coffe-nosugar\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Hot Chocolate\",\r\n    \"description\": \"\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Tea\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": \"tea\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Red Tea\",\r\n    \"description\": \" \",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Tea\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": \"tea\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Green Tea\",\r\n    \"description\": \" \",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Tea\"\r\n  },\r\n  {\r\n    \"id\": \"fresh-juice\",\r\n    \"name\": \"Orange\",\r\n    \"description\": \"\",\r\n    \"amount\": \"0.0\",\r\n    \"image\": \"\",\r\n    \"category\": \"Juice\"\r\n  }\r\n]"

if let data = menu.data(using: .utf8) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let menus = try decoder.decode([Menu].self, from: data)
            let categorizedMenu = Dictionary(grouping: menus) { $0.category }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

This line does the trick, what happens here is we group the array of objects by property which is **category**:

```
Dictionary(grouping: menus) { $0.category }
```

By the way in my answer, I added a new property which is **category** in the object, not advisable to group objects by **id** since **id** is always **unique**.